# Relative clause with infinitive verbal form and "from" preposition ("{subject} from whose {element} to get something")

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, relative-clauses, infinitive-phrases

Let use have a subject, which will refer to as the "parent".
This parent can have sub-elements, which will refer to as "child".

Now let us say I want to describe the action of getting something *from* a children with an infinitive verbal form in a relative clause, with the parent being the subject of the phrase.

Is it correct to do it like so?

> The parent from whose children to get something

or maybe (which I believe would be equivalent to the first):

> The parent, the children of which to get something from

Or is such a relative clause incorrect?

---

Edit: My question is not really about the difference between `whose` and `which`. I use `of which` in the second phrase, which I believe can be [used in place of `whose`](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/452489/whose-and-of-which) (the "parent" and "children" actually don't refer to people but objects). Granted, the use of `of which` in the original second phrase was probably wrong, and the new one is at best cumbersome.

My question is more about the correctness of creating a relative clause with an infinitive verbal form and the `from` preposition.

---

To clarify, the context I want to use this phrase in is programming: I want to describe a parameter of a function, which is usually done using infinitive phrases (e.g. "the stuff to update", "the thing to delete"...)

Comment: I clarified my question (the core problem being not the difference between `whose` and `which` but the correctness of such a relative clause).

Comment: Ted your question is both rather long and unclear - which is probably why no-one has tried to answer it. It would benefit greatly from being shortened and clarified.